# Query Builder receiving MySqlConnection for `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, jenssegers-mongodb

I am having trouble setting up a MongoDB-based Laravel 8 app using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`.
After setting up the necessary resource controllers, routes and models, calling any of the API routes results in the following error:

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::__construct(): Argument #1 ($connection) must be of type Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection, Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection given, called in <\path\to\vendor\jenssegers\mongodb\src\Eloquent\Model.php>
```

I assume the system is applying a default SQL connection due to some missing configuration, however all help resources I found were out of date. My local `.env` contains the additional lines below, but is otherwise untouched from the default example. Changing `DB_CONNECTION=` to `mongodb` did not change anything during troubleshooting:

```
MONGO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=database
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=
```

Furthermore, the beginning of the model class in question looks like this:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

Hopefully you can help me find the missing . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the driver in your `.env` or config file?

Comment: Sadly yes. As mentioned above I set up the entries in .env and I also added the connection entry in config/database.php

Comment: After some troubleshooting, turns out I needed to set the model object's `$connection = 'mongodb'`.